# How to filter Sharepoint Terms in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

How can I filter Sharepoint Terms by name using Microsoft Graph API?

Here is a sample of results returned by the request without filter:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#termStore/groups('xxxxxxxxx')/sets('xxxxxx')/terms",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "fb0d9476-4cec-46d5-acd5-12245de95308",
            "createdDateTime": "2017-06-28T15:07:44.18Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-03-12T11:31:36.137Z",
            "labels": [
                {
                    "name": "Hello",
                    "isDefault": true,
                    "languageTag": "en-US"
                }
            ],
            "descriptions": []
        },
```

I tried to filter like this:

- `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/termStore/groups/xxxx/sets/xxxx/terms?filter=labels/name eq 'Hello'`;
- and with expand: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/termStore/groups/xxxx/sets/xxxx/terms?labels($filter=name eq 'Hello')`.

But any request worked (`Invalid filter clause`, `Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Property 'labels' on type 'microsoft.graph.termStore.term' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.`).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the filter like the below:

```
?$filter=labels/any(s:s/name eq 'Hello')
```

Comment: How can it be translated with .Net Sdk? I need to search in the collection of the Terms but I always get "Invalid filter clause".
I tried like this:
.Filter($"startswith(labels/name, '{idTerm}')")